# Binding rows based on common id

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a very simple case where I want to combine several data frames into one based on a common id elements of a particular data frame.

Example:

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3)
x <- c(10, 12, 14)

data1 <- data.frame(id, x)
  
id <- c(2, 3)
x <- c(20, 22)

data2 <- data.frame(id, x)

id <- c(1, 3)
x <- c(30, 32)

data3 <- data.frame(id, x)
```

Which gives us,

```
$data1
  id  x
1  1 10
2  2 12
3  3 14

$data2
  id  x
1  2 20
2  3 22

$data3
  id  x
1  1 30
2  3 32
```

Now, I want to combine all three data frames based on the id's of the data3. The expected output should look like

```
> comb
  id  x
1  1 10
2  1 NA
3  1 30
4  3 14
5  3 22
6  3 32
```

I am trying the following, but not getting the expected output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
combined <- bind_rows(data1, data2, data3, .id = "id") %>% arrange(id)
```

Any idea how to get the expected output?

Comment: Why is there no 2 in the final dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bind_rows(data1, data2, data3, .id = 'grp')%>%
  complete(id, grp)%>%
  select(-grp) %>%
  filter(id%in%data3$id) 

# A tibble: 6 x 2
     id     x
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10
2     1    NA
3     1    30
4     3    14
5     3    22
6     3    32
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data1 %>% full_join(data2, by = 'id') %>% full_join(data3, by = 'id') %>% arrange(id) %>% right_join(data3, by = 'id') %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>% select(-name) %>% distinct()
# A tibble: 6 x 2
     id value
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10
2     1    NA
3     1    30
4     3    14
5     3    22
6     3    32
```

Answer (score 2):

Combine the 3 dataframes in one list and use `filter` to select only the `id`'s in 3rd dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bind_rows(data1, data2, data3, .id = "new_id") %>%
  filter(id %in% id[new_id == 3]) %>%
  complete(new_id, id)

#  new_id    id     x
#  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 1          1    10
#2 1          3    14
#3 2          1    NA
#4 2          3    22
#5 3          1    30
#6 3          3    32
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure base R solution can also make it

```
lst <- list(data1, data2, data3)
reshape(
  subset(
    reshape(
      do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, lst, grp = seq_along(lst))),
      idvar = "id",
      timevar = "grp",
      direction = "wide"
    ),
    id %in% lst[[3]]$id
  ),
  idvar = "id",
  varying = -1,
  direction = "long"
)[c("id", "x")]
```

which gives

```
    id  x
1.1  1 10
3.1  3 14
1.2  1 NA
3.2  3 22
1.3  1 30
3.3  3 32
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
do.call(rbind, unname(lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^data\\d+$")), \(x) {
        x1 <- subset(x, id %in% data3$id)
        v1 <- setdiff(data3$id, x1$id)
        if(length(v1) > 0) rbind(x1, cbind(id = v1, x = NA)) else x1
    })))
```

-output

```
    id  x
1   1 10
3   3 14
2   3 22
11  1 NA
12  1 30
21  3 32
```